# How to make soft delete in cascade with Entity Framework Core including navigation properties?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I can get all the entities marked as IsDeleted = true, applying query filters,
where IsDeleted is a field of my entities.

Now, my question is very simple, how to make a soft delete in cascade with Entity Framework Core when I am soft deleting an entity that has navigation properties that I want to mark as IsDeleted too.

Comment: Have you figured it out? for me, it works only if I eagerly load the sub-entity and call remove on it.

Comment: @JSON for the moment the solutions was to go recursively on your structure flagging your entities with IsDelete = true. I put the question on GitHub for them https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11240

Comment: Also calling the collection and apply remove to it along with the entity will mark both as deleted. I am trying to figure out how to take advantage of the EF cascade delete but no clue how to implement it in my code

Comment: @JSON please check again in the github question the last answer from ajcvickers, that should be the idea

Answer (score 5):

I use following code to accomplish a cascading delete. Thanks to @Zinov and ajcvickers. Based on https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/11240

```
//..
case EntityState.Deleted:
    entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
    entry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
    foreach (var navigationEntry in entry.Navigations.Where(n => !n.Metadata.IsDependentToPrincipal()))
    {
        if (navigationEntry is CollectionEntry collectionEntry)
        {
            foreach (var dependentEntry in collectionEntry.CurrentValue)
            {
                HandleDependent(Entry(dependentEntry));
            }
        }
        else
        {
            var dependentEntry = navigationEntry.CurrentValue;
            if (dependentEntry != null)
            {
                HandleDependent(Entry(dependentEntry));
            }
        }
    }
    break;
}

private void HandleDependent(EntityEntry entry)
{
    entry.CurrentValues["IsDeleted"] = true;
}
```

Comment: mmm, @jannikb this looks like ajcvickers answer, I was the one who posted the question there

Comment: As he stated this leads to performance issues. Any new solutions?

Comment: `IsDependentToPrincipal()` extension is deprecated, does someone have another solution?

Answer (score 3):

You can implement these two step basicly for make cascade soft delete.

**First**, write a event for override SaveChanges.

```
private void DbContextBase_SavingChanges(object? sender, SavingChangesEventArgs e)
    {
        var objectContext = (DbContextBase)sender;
        var modifiedEntities =
            objectContext.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(c => c.State is EntityState.Added or EntityState.Modified or EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var entry in modifiedEntities)
        {
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                entry.Property("CreatedTime").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                entry.Property("ModifiedTime").CurrentValue = DateTime.UtcNow;
            }
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Deleted)
            {
                entry.Property("IsDeleted").CurrentValue = true;
                entry.State = EntityState.Modified;
            }
        }
    }
```

Implement from DbContext constructor

```
protected ExampleDbContext(DbContextOptions options) : base(options)
    {
        this.SavingChanges += DbContextBase_SavingChanges;
    }
```

**Secondly**, just make navigation property cascade delete on configuration.

```
builder.HasMany<ExampleNavigationEntity>(c => c.ExampleNavigation).WithOne().OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

Comment: This looks pretty good, even cascade delete is working. Nice!